# Simple question on finding Watts and Wrms

Tags: power-electronics, watts, calculation

I've done a bit of research but can't find the explanation for this problem, at least mathematically.

I'm calculating W and Wrms of an audio amplifier by knowing output Vpeak and Load resistance. It's all pretty much theoretical so I'm assuming Rload is not inductive.

Having Vpeak = 80 V and Rload = 16 ohm

I would generally use the formula Wpeak = Vpeak x (Vpeak/Rload)
which gives me Wpeak= 400W

I convert Vpeak to Vrms by multiplying 80 V x 0.707 = 56.56 Vrms

I would assume Wrms to be Wrms = Vrms x (Vrms/Rload)
which gives me Wrms= 199.93 Wrms

now why if I multiply Wrms x 1.414 (which it's the constant to get the peak value from RMS value) it comes out as 282.7 W which is less than 400 W?

Which one is the right Wpeak?

Comment: Because the voltage is *squared*, i.e., Vp x Vp, and 0.707... x 0.707... [Sq Rt of 2 times itself] = **2**. BTW, this assumes sound is sinusoidal, which it is *not* (not much info in a continuous pure sine wave).

Comment: \$ \Large P = \frac{V_{peak}^2}{2 R_L} =  \frac{80V^2}{2* 16\Omega} = 200W \$

Comment: Rms watts do not exist, this is marketing BS. When you integrate the instantaneous power \$p(t)\$, you obtain an *average* power expressed in watts. And if you multiply rms currents and voltages when your amp is loaded by a resistance, then you also end up with an average power whose unit is watt.

Comment: Only voltage or current are ever given as RMS quantities; talking about RMS power is nonsensical.

Comment: What you refer to as rms power is actually average power and average power is half of peak power.     Vrms * Irms = average power = (Vpk * Ipk)/2 = peak power/2

Comment: The formula I like to memorize is \$V_{_\text{PEAK}}=\sqrt{ \vphantom{P^2} 2 \, R_{_\text{LOAD}} \, P_{_\text{PEAK}}}\$. This allows me to figure out the voltage rails needed for a (single-ended output) audio amplifier (after adding in various overhead voltages, doubling the result if I'm using a single rail supply. (Bridged situations are different, of course.)

Comment: When I did PA amplifier design for a major brand, we were well aware that RMS was BS but what the customers were after was power during bass drum/kick for the vast majority of music so they were optimized for as high average power as possible for some 10s of ms and repetition frequency in the 150 bpm range. Works for most. Stated power was what it could do average during said kick. Then dubstep became popular which pushed up the requirements on average continuous power a lot. It’s not economically feasible to have a special design for some EDMers, so they got to buy the bigger model and derate

Comment: @jonk Is it me or should that Ppeak in your formula actually be Pav

Comment: @James Sorry. I should have been clearer in my writing. (I'm deleting that comment as confusing.) I used PEAK and probably should have found a different word (like MAXAVG or something.) What I mean is that **P** represents the maximum power you expect to continuously deliver. It is technically also an average. So I didn't mean to suggest differently.

Comment: @jonk Maximum average power rather than the peak power which occurs at the peak of the voltage waveform?

Comment: @James Yeah. That's better. I was writing terribly. Sorry about that. Now I wish I'd used \$P_{_\text{MAXAVG}}\$ in my earlier writing. Lots less confusing.

Comment: @VerbalKint I was under the impression that integrating instantaneous power over time T would obtain the energy used over the time period T in Joules. Energy is the integral of instantaneous power. To obtain the average power you'd need to divide that energy by T because  E=V * I * T and power = V * I = (P * I * T)/T and so power is measured in Joules/second = Watts.

Comment: Sales people say, "Peak Watts" or "Maximum Power" because that fake number is double the real power number that uses RMS voltages.

Comment: @James, of course, a better word would have been *average* the instantaneous power \$p(t)\$. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watts peak makes sense.

Watts RMS does not (because there is no such thing). You are calculating watts average.

> I would generally use the formula \$ W_{peak} = V_{peak} \frac {V_{peak}}{R_{load}} \$ which gives me W<sub>peak</sub>= 400W.

That's fine.

> I convert Vpeak to Vrms by multiplying 80v x 0.707 = 56.56Vrms

> I would assume Wrms to be Wrms = Vrms x (Vrms/Rload) which gives me Wrms= 199.93Wrms

OK, except that that's average power, not RMS power.

> Now why if I multiply Wrms x 1.414 (which it's the constant to get the peak value from RMS value) it comes out as 282.7 W which is less than 400 W?

If you multiply your average power, 200 W, by \$ \sqrt 2 \sqrt 2 \$ you'll get 400 W. The reason is that power is proportional to V<sup>2</sup>.

Comment: "The reason is that power is proportional to V2." That's what I needed! thanks.
I now understand Wrms not being useful and a thing, I guess I was misled as working in audio you often see Watt RMS on equipment labels to describe the average power the speaker or amp operate at. Why wouldn't they just call it average power?

Comment: It's marketing technobabble to make things sound impressive.

Answer (score 2):

You can measure power at any instant such as peak or averaged over 1 cycle, never RMS power.

THe sine power appears as a sinusoidal power of 2f ranging from 0 to peak with a flat average of 50% of the peak with the product of V(t)I(t).

THe peak load for +/80V into 16 Ohms is 400 Wp and 200 Wavg .

Assuming 100% efficiency, the peak power generated is -400W and -200W average.

[Demo](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxGwBYQlLsaBTAWjDACgAnESsQ7vbr3AY+kcITYA3CghTC+2WfyjhuYvGM1RoCNgHdBfSgMVzjUfYfky5YERcqR6dhXNzVioqAH1Clb5DelIRgxN4avtD+LN4oAd7YbI70wdRgKAIIxLbZKoF+3hjeYJQ82GEw8GABsHDVMdWOkElO1qxukGm5YtUFRSVlFbWQ1ZV13g1BcGzYAmIAYhA9yBAsIABKDADOAJZbAC4AhgB2AMYMbEA)

Answer (score 1):

The term ‘RMS’ applies to voltage and current.  It does not apply to power.  So that’s part of the problem.